# Is it possible to use forms to change aspects of a website permanently?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, save

I am trying to create a website that will allow me and my coworkers to track the status of equipment in our building. I want to be able to click on a button (representing the piece of equipment) and have a form pop up that allows you to change the color of the button, add a link for our internal tracking, and add notes via a text box BUT (and this is the part i need help on).... I want that information to be displayed when I access the same site at a later time, or if another person accesses the site.

[Picture of what it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mb6N3.png)

I am very new to coding, but this is what I have so far. This just creates a header, paragraph, and button link. This accomplishes what I want, but it does not have the ability to add, edit, or save changes.

HTML

```
<button class="button" onclick="myfunction1()"> Equipment A </button>
<button class="button" onclick="myfunction2()"> Equipment B </button>
<h1 id="header"></h1>
<p id="description"></p>
```

JS

```
function myfunction1() {
ClearButtons()
document.getElementById("header").innerHTML = "Equipment A";
document.getElementById("description").innerHTML = "Issue with Equipment";
var form = document.createElement("form");
 form.setAttribute("action","https://   link to internal website that tracks issues ")
 form.setAttribute("class","removeable")
 var inp = document.createElement("input")
 inp.setAttribute("type","submit")
 inp.setAttribute("value","LINK")
 form.appendChild(inp)
 var inp2 = document.createElement("input")
 inp2.setAttribute("type","radio")
 inp2.setAttribute("value","Operational")
 form.appendChild(inp2)
 var inp3 = document.createElement("input")
 inp3.setAttribute("type","radio")
 inp3.setAttribute("value","NonOperational")
 form.appendChild(inp3)
document.body.appendChild(form);
}

function ClearButtons(){
$("form").remove(".removeable")
}
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated, even if it is just pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: You're going to need some server-side code, and (preferably) a database.  If you don't have a developer then this may be an uphill struggle, but you can do it as long as you don't have time restraints.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a specific type of coding that you would recommend based on what I described?

Comment: That's a massively broad and subjective question, but for a flat-out beginner I'd recommend looking at a mix of PHP (server-side application) and MySQL (database).  They're both free and popular, which will obviously help you getting the help you'll need.

Comment: Or you could use a data storage service like firebase. You are basically asking how to create a dynamic content website and there are numerous different approaches